# multiple H1 or H2 tags and possible multiple usage of meta description on overview page

Tags: seo, h1

Good day,

I want to make a page overview page where all pages of a website are listed. (or a specific collection of them) so that the reader has a clue what to find where. Just a bit like a HTML sitemap but then with page descriptions and h1 or h2 titles.

This page is intended for as well users as SEO.

Now my question is. I want to place many pages on that single page.

I was thinking of using bootstrap cards and in the the header using a H1 or H2 title for the page title.

Lets say something like

```
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header"><h1 class="card-tite">How to maintain your hairdryer</h1></div>
    <div class="card-body"><p>A hairdryer is a delicate piece of hardware. Especially the more modern ones. They are sometimes equipped with a microcomputer. Therefore it is important to always store them in a dry place</p></div>"
    <div class="card-footer"><a href="https://example.com/hairdryer-maintenance">read more</a></div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header"><h1 class="card-tite">Where to buy a hairdryer</h1></div>
    <div class="card-body"><p>A hairdryer can be bought almost everywhere. But we recommend buying your hairdryer at a specialist hairdryer store</p></div>"
    <div class="card-footer"><a href="https://example.com/where-to-buy-a-hair">read more</a></div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header"><h1 class="card-tite">Repair a broken hairdryer</h1></div>
    <div class="card-body"><p>A hairdryer is almost always thrown away when broken. However only a few know that many hairdryers can be easily repaired by a certified specialist</p></div>"
    <div class="card-footer"><a href="https://example.com/repair-your-hairdryer">read more</a></div>
</div>
```

Now I have two questions.

#1 how big of a deal is it to use multiple H1 or H2 tags?
Or shouldn't I use a header tag for this?

Keep in mind that the example above might have about 30 h1 tags to maybe 3000 h1 tags in extreme cases.

So should I still use H1 tags or maybe H2 tags in that matter?

Then question #2

I want to have the option to write a specific text for this purpose that will be displayed on this page.

BUT if the user didn't fill in this specific text. Am I "allowed" to use the page meta description text as an alternative.

And in allowed I mean is it any sensitive to do this SEO wise?

Comment: Using Multiple h1 tags is not in line with the semantic usage of the tag, multiple h2 tags can be used. Google does not want automated robot content, using the meta tags from other pages "verbatim" may lead google to the impression a robot created the page, but a one or two-off usage of the same text or a quote may not be a big deal ...